# HTML5 'touchmove' event does not fire on canvas if started outside of it

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

When I try to swipe over a canvas starting outside of it, event listener attached to one does not receive 'touchmove' event. In other words, I need to register touchmove that bagan on parent node.

Is there a way to propagate this event from parent element to canvas? Any solution including opensource jquery plugins is acceptable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to register `mousemove` or `touchmove` event on canvas parent element and to propagate the event to the `canvas`. In other words when you hold the mouse on the canvas parent this to be captured by the canvas itself?

Comment: Yes, but with one condition - it should be captured by canvas only when finger reaches canvas area

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with this approach is that the events captured on the parent element are going to propagate to child elements. A possible solution would be to listen for `touch` or `mouse` events on the parent node and then check if the finger is touching the outside elements. If so dispatch the `mousemove` or `touchmove` events on the canvas itself then capture this event on the canvas.

We will test the mouse pointer to be on the canvas area and we will dispatch the `touch` event only on this case. This way the event will be captured by canvas only when finger reaches canvas area.

I've created a snippet for illustration. I've provided example for `mousemove` events, but you can extend to `touchmove` events too. I didn't included the canvas event listener main part, i only consoled a simple message.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="canvas-holder">
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var canvasHolder = document.getElementsByClassName('canvas-holder')[0];
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var offsetX = canvas.offsetLeft;
var offsetY = canvas.offsetTop;

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,1)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

var canvasPosLeft = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
var canvasPosTop = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
var canvasPosRight = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().right;
var canvasPosBottom = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
event.initMouseEvent('mousemove', true, true, window, 1, 100, 100, 100, 100);

// Listen for the event.
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) { 
    // main logic here...
    console.log('mouse triggered');
}, false);

canvasHolder.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var posX = e.clientX;
    var posY = e.clientY;

    if ((posX < canvasPosLeft || posX > canvasPosRight ) ||
        (posY < canvasPosTop || posY > canvasPosBottom ))  {

        // Dispatch the event.
        canvas.dispatchEvent(event);     
    }
});
```

And here is the **fiddle**:

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g3k1mkhy/1/)</kbd>